# .xll in different format than specified by file extension

Tags: c++, excel, visual-studio-2010, xll

I tried creating a very simple .xll in VS2010 (using C++) that includes a simple addition function.

I've included xlcall32.lib & frmwrk32.lib (from 2007 Excel SDK) using the Project Properties menu in Visual Studio and exported the function with xlAutoOpen using a .def and when opening the .xll in Dependency Walker there are no errors shown and it displays the 2 functions to be exported.

For information I'm using Win7 machine and trying to load the .xll in Excel 2007.

Does anybody have any ideas as to what could be causing this? I haven't tried using xll.codeplex.com yet as getting programs installed in my company takes an incredibly long time and I'd like to get this up and running ASAP.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say exactly what the problem is. I'm guessing Excel won't recognise your XLL. You mention two functions to be exported: one of them xlAutoOpen. You also need to export xlAutoClose and xlAddInManagerInfo. And possibly xlAutoFree too.

See these links...
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/178474/EN-US/
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andreww/archive/2007/12/09/building-an-excel-xll-in-c-c-with-vs-2008.aspx